# Change windows registry of Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I want to use Microsoft provided image and do the registry change for disabling weak ciphers and TLS.
What is the best way to change registry of Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set as a part of the provisioning process

Comment: Do you know how to change the registry to disable weak ciphers and TLS inside the VM?

Comment: Please see the following links. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings#:~:targetText=To%20disable%20TLS%201.0%20for,the%20DWORD%20value%20to%201
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/187498/how-to-disable-pct-1-0-ssl-2-0-ssl-3-0-or-tls-1-0-in-internet-informat

Comment: You can write a PowerShell script to do that and use the VM extension to execute the script.

Comment: Any more questions? Do you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the best way is to [execute scripts on Azure VMs with Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-deploy-app#already-provisioned). Scripts can be downloaded from Azure storage or GitHub, or provided to the Azure portal at extension run-time. For more information on how to install an app with a Custom Script Extension, see the following tutorials:

- [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-install-apps-cli)
- [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-install-apps-powershell)
- [Azure Resource Manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-install-apps-template)

Addtionally, you could use [Set-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-6) or [reg add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add) to create a registry entry and value.
For example,

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\ContosoCompany" -Name "NoOfEmployees" -Value 823
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\ContosoCompany"

PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\contosocompany
PSParentPath  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software
PSChildName   : contosocompany
PSDrive       : HKLM
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
NoOfLocations : 2
NoOfEmployees : 823
```